# Converting C# code to VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net

i tried converting this code from c#

```
a += (uint)(url[k + 0] + (url[k + 1] << 8) + (url[k + 2] << 16) + (url[k + 3] << 24));
```

to vb,net i get this

```
a += CUInt(url(k + 0) + (url(k + 1) << 8) + (url(k + 2) << 16) + (url(k + 3) << 24))
```

an i get this error

> Operator '<<' is not defined for types 'Char' and 'Integer'.

Can anyone help me with a correction

EDIT

uint a, b;

a = b = 0x9E3779B9;

url = string

Comment: what is the array `url`?

Comment: What type is the url array? Char? Also, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i got some info about the error that c# automatically truncates integer overflow, which vb.net does not. so it was suggested that i should turn off integer overflow check, but it still does not correct the error am getting

Comment: @MyK What was that reason, again? You know the syntax for C# but not for VB.NET? I fail to see how that's a language inadequacy...

Comment: Hello Smith. Were you able to successfully port this perfect hash function by Bob Jenkins to VB.Net? I am looking for this function in VB.Net.

Comment: no, not really, i got so many errors thats not wort the stress. i had to compile in c# dll instead. please if you find the solution, can you let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem seems to be that C# will allow bit-shifting on a char whereas VB does not.

So you would need something like (untested)

```
 CUInt( ... + (CUint( url(k + 1) ) << 8) + ... )
```

But it does look like a rather weak HashCode.

Comment: i did that, an i got `'Char' values cannot be converted to 'UInteger'. Use 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW' to interpret a character as a Unicode value or 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Val' to interpret it as a digit.`

Comment: Like I said, I didn't try or test it. Looks like you need AscW() instead of my inner CUInt().

Comment: i did this `(CUInt(AscW(url(k + 1))) << 8)` and got this error `Operator '+' is not defined for types 'Char' and 'UInteger'.`

Comment: Hmmm, the only `+` there is `k+1`... Must be something else. Break it down into little steps.

Comment: Change *every* url(...)  into AscW(url(...))

Comment: @MarkJ you can be sure i have done that, and i posed the result in the third comment

Comment: @Smith No offence, but I would like to be absolutely sure you *really have* changed *every* one. Because this compiles for me `a += CUInt(AscW(url(k + 0)) + (AscW(url(k + 1)) << 8) + (AscW(url(k + 2)) << 16) + (AscW(url(k + 3)) << 24))` but on the other hand *this* `a += CUInt(url(k + 0) + (AscW(url(k + 1)) << 8) + (AscW(url(k + 2)) << 16) + (AscW(url(k + 3)) << 24))` , where I have not wrapped `url(k+0)` in `AscW`,  gives compile error `Operator '+' is not defined for types 'Char' and 'Integer'`

Comment: thanks i appreciate, but i get `Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.` in the line `a += CUInt(AscW(url(k + 0)) + (AscW(url(k + 1)) << 8) + (AscW(url(k + 2)) << 16) + (AscW(url(k + 3)) << 24))`. so what do i do now?

Comment: Well, should it be allowed to overflow? The posted code is too short.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know VB but I would suspect you can just cast each url(k+n) first i.e.

```
(CUint(url(k+2))<< 8)
```

I'm also assuming a CUint is 32 bits 
Assuming you are trying to create a 32 bit int out of 4 chars there is probably more checking you can do but at a minimum I would turn this into two methods ConvertCharArrayToUint() and another one that does each shift ShiftCharLeft(char, numBits) and hide all the casting ugliness in there. I'm surprised in C# you can shift a char like that.

**EDIT:** Try doing this on separate lines while you're figuring it out

```
int part_0 = Val(url(k));
int part_1 = Val(url(k+1));
int part_2 = Val(url(k+2));
...
int shifted_1 = part_1 << 8;
...
int result = part_0 + shifted_1...
```

They you can step through with the debugger, check types etc and get a full understanding of what is going on, then you can refactor for whatever readability you prefer.

Comment: i tried it an got the same error `'Char' values cannot be converted to 'UInteger'. Use 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW' to interpret a character as a Unicode value or 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Val' to interpret it as a digit.`

Comment: OK sounds like instead of using a CUInt cast you have to wrap it in a call to Val(url(k+2)) then shift the result.

Comment: thanks, how would i convert the first part `url(k + 0)`, i did this **url(k + 0) + Val(url(k)) + (Val(url(k + 2)) << 8)**, and i got another error  `Operator '+' is not defined for types 'Char' and 'Integer'.` vb underlined this **url(k + 0) + Val(url(k))**

Comment: You have to wrap the first one also, see the first line of my example under EDIT int part_1 = Val(url(k));

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7haw1dex%28v=vs.71%29.aspx be sure that you use supported types.

Comment: throw more light on your answer