# Bob Jenkins perfect hash function in VB.Net

Tags: c#, vb.net, hash

I am trying to convert Bob Jenkins perfect hash function from C# to VB.Net and I am stuck at following.

```
a += (UInt32)(url[k + 0] + (url[k + 1] << 8) + (url[k + 2] << 16) + (url[k + 3] << 24))
```

How can I write above statement in VB.Net?

Please note the following:

a is UInt32
url is String
k is Integer

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
a += url(k + 0) + (url(k + 1) << 8) + (url(k + 2) << 16) + (url(k + 3) << 24)
```

To avoid manually doing type casting, I am using "Option Strict Off"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting C# code to VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333540/converting-c-sharp-code-to-vb-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the answer from this page. See answer by Henk Holterman and comments by MarkJ.

[Converting C# code to VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333540/converting-c-sharp-code-to-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

I think, vb does`t support typecasting from string to integer (by char values).
Use `Val(Mid(url,k,1))` to convert char to integer and do shifts and other math operations on it.