# VB.NET code returning different result than C# code

Tags: c#, vb.net, bit-manipulation, runtime-error

The following code in C# gives result "228452386"

```
UInt32 a;

int k = 0;

a = 0x9E3779B9;

a += (UInt32)(url[k + 0] + (url[k + 1] << 8) + (url[k + 2] << 16) + (url[k + 3] << 24));
```

After above code is ran, "a" contains "228452386".

But the following same code in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET) results in "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow". Basically the last statement is returning value "1868983913", so the runtime error is generated.

```
Dim a As UInt32

Dim k As Integer = 0

a = &H9E3779B9UI

a += CUInt(AscW(url(k + 0)) + (AscW(url(k + 1)) << 8) + (AscW(url(k + 2)) << 16) + (AscW(url(k + 3)) << 24))
```

Please note the variable "url" in the above code could be any string and it is same for both codes.

When I run the following statements in both C# and VB.NET than they both return same value

C#

```
(UInt32)(url[k + 0] + (url[k + 1] << 8) + (url[k + 2] << 16) + (url[k + 3] << 24))
```

VB.NET

```
CUInt(AscW(url(k + 0)) + (AscW(url(k + 1)) << 8) + (AscW(url(k + 2)) << 16) + (AscW(url(k + 3)) << 24))
```

Both statements return the value "1868983913" for "url" "info:microsoft.com". But when I run the complete statement with **a += .........** then VB.NET gives an error while C# returns the value "228452386".

Comment: You should probably use `Asc` instead of `AscW`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zew1e4wc(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: @SaniHuttunen
Asc also gives same error.

Comment: To remove the error you need to disable integer overflow checks in the Advanced Compiler Options dialog.

Comment: You have started 3 questions about this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241027/bob-jenkins-perfect-hash-function-in-vb-net, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242355/vb-net-code-returning-different-result-than-c-sharp-code, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333540/converting-c-sharp-code-to-vb-net

Comment: @DejanJanjušević
They are all related to different problems.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen
Even if I turn it off, I guess my problem will remain and that is in case of VB.Net it is returning different value for same string.

Comment: @SaniHuttunen
You are right. I made a mistake earlier but when I turned off this feature I got correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an overflow, because the result of adding the two numbers you're adding are larger than what fits in an UInt.

The resulting number is a 33 bit number, UInts fit only 32 bits.

- In C#, the most significant bit is just chopped of, keeping the 32 bits that fit inside the UInt. (This new value is not the actual result of adding your numbers.)
- In VB.NET you get an exception stating that the number doesn't fit.

The VB.NET compiler (or VS) allows you to turn of this overflow checking, so that VB.NET will behave like C# in this case.

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET automatically inserts tests for overflow, while C# doesn't. The equivalent C# code would be:

```
UInt32 a;
int k = 0;
a = 0x9E3779B9;
checked{
    a += (UInt32)(url[k + 0] + (url[k + 1] << 8) + (url[k + 2] << 16) + (url[k + 3] << 24));
}
```

**EDIT**: Changed code sample to comply with edited question.

Comment: Basically I want equivalent code for VB.Net based on C# code.

Comment: I didn't find the equivalent "unchecked" keyword for VB. (Don't know if it has.) But you can turn of overflow checks for your VB.NET application, as stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4515123/19594

Comment: Please check my EDIT above as I have added more info.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following VB.NET code:

```
    a += CUInt(AscW(url(k + 0))) + CUInt((AscW(url(k + 1)) << 8)) + CUInt((AscW(url(k + 2)) << 16)) + CUInt((AscW(url(k + 3)) << 24))
```

`AscW` returns an Integer (signed) and what you need is unsigned.

*EDIT*

This works:

```
    Dim a As Int64
    Dim result As UInt32

    Dim k As Integer = 0

    Dim url As String = "info:microsoft.com"

    a = &H9E3779B9UI

    Dim a1 As UInt32 = 0
    Dim a2 As UInt32 = 0
    Dim a3 As UInt32 = 0
    Dim a4 As UInt32 = 0

    a1 = AscW(url(k + 0))
    a2 = AscW(url(k + 1)) << 8
    a3 = AscW(url(k + 2)) << 16
    a4 = AscW(url(k + 3)) << 24

    a = (a + a1 + a2 + a3 + a4) And &HFFFFFFF
    result = Convert.ToUInt32(a)
```

Comment: I got same error when I used the above statement because it is also giving value "1868983913" as stated in my original problem above.

Comment: It returned the same value on my PC, which string did you use for url?

Comment: Please check my EDIT above as I have added more info.